# Is UIWebview dependent on Wifi?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have this following piece of code, which loads `UIWebView` properly on one Wifi but doesn't on another WiFi. It again works properly on 3G.

```
tempWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
tempWebView.delegate = self;
tempWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

[tempWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com/Contact.html"]]];
```

I tried `NSLogging` and it seems the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is not getting called on 2nd Wifi.

Could I blame network 2 or is there something I need to check?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but I would add http:// (or https://) to your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is quite sure not related to your code. Perhaps the one WiFi just had no internet connection!? Or there was some strange network setup? Did Safari or other apps work in there?

If your code works in 3G, or in a single WiFi, than your code is fine.

Comment: I used Apple's Reachability Code and looks like LAN & internet are functioning. 

Safari is opening the page properly on 2nd Wifi.

I hope the router has some screwed up setup.

Can we add something to UIwebview delegate methods?

Comment: but if safari can, your app should also.. have you tried to put http in front of your url? perhaps the DHCP fails or anything..!? Did you debug your code - that means to look at the created NSURL, URLRequest, any errors and all delegate callbacks?